# Calling functions inside other functions in Python

Tags: python, function, args

I'm trying to write a simple program that creates a **square grid** like this:

```
    + - - - - + - - - - +
    |         |         |
    |         |         |
    |         |         |
    |         |         |
    + - - - - + - - - - +
    |         |         |
    |         |         |
    |         |         |
    |         |         |
    + - - - - + - - - - +
```

I want it to take an input x, which defines how many cells are in each row/column. The script is as follows:

```
def repeat(x, f, *args): 
    for i in range(x): f(*args)

def topx(x):
    print x*top + '+'

def midx(x):
    print x*mid + '|'

def block(f,g,*args):
    f(*args)
    g(*args)

top = str('+ - - - - ')
mid = str('|         ')
x = 2
repeat(x,block,topx,repeat,x,4,midx,x)
topx()
```

I get the following **error** when I try to run the script:

```
TypeError: topx() takes exactly 1 argument (4 given)
```

It's something to do with the arguments in the block function, but can't figure out how to get around it.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

Thanks for the pointers, I rewrote it slightly as follows and it works nicely. I also changed it to allow you to choose the number of columns and rows independently.

```
def repeat(x, f, *args): 
    for i in range(x): f(*args)

def topx(x):
    print x*top + '+'

def midx(x):
    print x*mid + '|'

def row(x):
    topx(x)
    repeat(4,midx,x)

top = str('+ - - - - ')
mid = str('|         ')
x = 3 
y = 4 
repeat(y,row,x)
topx(x)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def topx(x):
    print x*top + '+'
```

This takes one argument: `x`. But when you call it:

```
def block(f,g,*args):
    f(*args) # This is what calls topx
    g(*args)
```

You're passing it `*args`, which contains `[x, 4, midx, x]`. And that's four arguments right there.

You should probably reconsider your structure to fix this. Perhaps a class?

Answer (score 0):

```
def grid(x, space=4):
    for i in range(x):
        print ("+" + "-"*space)*x + "+"
        for j in range(space):
            print ("|" + " "*space)*x + "|"
    print ("+" + "-"*space)*x + "+"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not  best way. but your script can be easily updated to be more readable and working.

```
cell_number = 2

top = str('+ - - - - ')
mid = str('|         ')

def repeat(cell_number, f, *args): 
    """
    repeat call of function `f` `call_number` times
    """
    for i in range(cell_number): 
        f(*args)

def topx(cell_number):
    """
    draw horizontal edge
    """
    print cell_number * top + '+'

def midx(cell_number):
    """
    draw middle part with vertical edges
    """
    print cell_number * mid + '|'

def block(cell_num):
    """
    draw one row of `cell_num` cells
    """
    topx(cell_num)
    repeat((len(top) - 1)/2, midx, cell_num)

repeat(cell_number, block, cell_number)
topx(cell_number)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def box(width, height, cell=1):

    print '+' + ('- ' * width + '+') * cell
    for x in range(cell):
        for x in range(height):
            print '|' + ('  ' * width + '|') * cell
        print '+' + ('- ' * width + '+') * cell
```